# Error during template rendering in DjangoCMS plugin from {% translate 'Clear' %}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms, templatetags

I’m trying to create a custom CMS Plugin and when i click to create the plugin this error happens:

[Error during template rendering from {% translate 'Clear' %}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smBne.png)

How can i solve this? In the past it was working. I don’t what happens.

Thank you!

I tryed to access the template "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filer/templates/admin/filer/widgets/admin_file.html" but i couldn't because it was build by docker.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: In my requirements.txt i have "Django==3.0.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 3.0 doesn't have `translate` tag, it used `trans` instead.
I suggest you update to 3.2 LTS version at least.